# Python array: force 'l' to be 4 bytes long

Tags: python, arrays, binaryfiles, long-integer

I have biary file, header + collection of 4 bytes long integer values.

After unpacking the header with `struct.unpack` I create array of the remaining values.

```
int_values = array.array('l')
int_values.fromfile(binary_input, self.columns * self.rows)
```

Under Windows everything works as expected.
Under my Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) I'm getting the following error:

```
int_values.fromfile(byn_input, self.columns * self.rows)
EOFError: not enough items in file
```

It seems like under Ubuntu `'l'` is expected to be 8 bytes long by default.
Using struct, I am able to declare mode by prefixes `'=, <, >, !'`

How could I force `array('l')` to be 4 bytes long, despite default 8 bytes?

Comment: But a long is eight bytes long, an int is 4 bytes. Use `i`.

Comment: What is your actual data? What's `self.columns`? What's `self.rows`? It seems your data is offset by the header or some other set of circumstances you haven't shown us.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In fact, I use this solution but I want to be absolute sure that this is valid. When I prepare binary file from ASCII, I pack the values as ```l```. If this is ok, please change your comment into the answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: These values are like ```3645, 3728,...```. ```self.colums``` and ```self.rows``` values are calculated from parameters stored in the header ```self.columns = int((self.boundary_east - self.boundary_west) / self.spacing_ew)
  self.rows = int((self.boundary_north - self.boundary_south) / self.spacing_ns)```